# Forgot password link is not working

Tags: users

I have a problem with my drupal 7 site. It could be registered to my site but "forgot password" section (link) is not working. What should I do to solve this problem?

In my authentication form there are 2 links: 1) Registration 2) Forgot password? For example when you click "Forgot password?" link, a letter comes to my e-mail. And there is a url in letter which takes you to my drupal site. If you click url (which takes you to my site) you are in the site now but there isn't reset password form

Comment: do you mean the "Request new password" tab or url "/user/password" are not working/missing?